# Banner Animado com Google Web Design

Tags: html, google

Eu criei um banner animado usando a ferramenta Google Web Design.
Pra quem já usou ele cria o banner com HTML5 CSS e Javascript.

para incorporar esse banner na minha página  eu utilizei a tag do HTML:

```
            <div class="row">

              <iframe src="banner/rodrigo.html" width="305" height="255"></iframe>

            </div>
```

Queria saber se essa é a forma correta de incorporar um banner animado em um site, ou se existe outra maneira, por exemplo: Fazer com que o google web design  salve como um arquivo SVG algo do tipo.

Comment: Você diz isso baseado nas limitações que o Google Web Design oferece a você ou em termos gerais de desenvolvimento com HTML e CSS?

Comment: é pq nunca tinha feito, um banner animado pra botar em uma página, ai quando fiz por padrão a ferramenta GWD cria uma página em html, e arquivos CSS e JS. ai unica forma que achei de incorporar esse banner foi pro IFRAME, ai queria saber se era assim que fazia mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abordando sua questão em termos gerais de desenvolvimento front-end e deixando um pouco de lado as possibilidades da ferramenta Google Web Design.

Há várias formas de se incluir sua página **banner/rodrigo.html**, digo que o atributo `iframe` não é a melhor opção para este caso, pois é muito limitado. Ressalto que `iframe` não necessariamente está errado, apenas que não é uma boa prática.

Se você estiver desenvolvendo com PHP, dinamicamente é possível incluir sua página da seguinte forma:

```
<?php include 'banner/rodrigo.html'; ?>
```

> Pratique a inclusão com PHP **[neste link.](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_includes.asp)**

Caso esteja apenas desenvolvendo o design em si, nada de conteúdo dinâmico, dá pra utilizar Javascript da seguinte forma:

Inclua a tag `<script>` na `<head>` do seu site, ela conterá a informação do arquivo a ser incluído e a `<div>` que será utilizada.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#include").load("banner/rodrigo.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="include"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

> Leia mais sobre da inclusão via Javascript **[neste tópico.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837835/include-html-in-another-html-file)**

*Como o Google Web Design deve incluir jquery, você não necessitará da tag que faz a chamada da biblioteca.

*Vale lembrar que não estou considerando o conteúdo de seu arquivo `banner/rodrigo.html`, o seu arquivo `.css`, conflitos de jquery, etc.